# github top directory same name as java project

Tags: git

my github repositories look like so:

```
organization/Project_Name/Project_Name/src...
```

why is this happening and is this a bad thing going forward?
Do I need to change this to avoid some problems down the line?

Comment: How do you create repositories and what do you commit first?

Comment: I use the EGIT plugin for eclipse. I just realized that in the GUI dialog, it shows the project name twice, in the 'Target Location'.